# Calculations across more than two different dataframes in R

Tags: r, cbind

I'm trying to transfer some work previously done in Excel into R. All I need to do is transform two basic count_if formulae into readable R script. In Excel, I would use three tables and calculate across those using 'point-and-click' methods, but now I'm lost in how I should address it in R.

My original dataframes are large, so for this question I've posted sample dataframes:

```
OperatorData <- data.frame(
                    Operator = c("A","B","C"),
                    Locations = c(850, 575, 2175)
 )

AreaData <- data.frame(
              Area = c("Torbay","Torquay","Tooting","Torrington","Taunton","Torpley"),
              SumLocations = c(1000,500,500,250,600,750)
 )

OperatorAreaData <- data.frame(
              Operator = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C"),
              Area = c("Torbay","Tooting","Taunton",
                       "Torbay","Taunton","Torrington",
                       "Tooting","Torpley","Torquay","Torbay","Torrington"),
              Locations = c(250,400,200,
                            100,400,75,
                            100,750,500,650,175)
 )
```

What I'm trying to do is add two new columns to the OperatorData dataframe: one indicating the count of Areas that operator operates in and another count indicating how many areas in which that operator operates in **and** owns more than 50% of locations.

So the new resulting dataframe would look like this

```
Operator     Locations   AreaCount    Own_GE_50percent
A            850         3            1
B            575         3            1
C            2715        5            4
```

So far, I've managed to calculate the first column using the table function and then appending:

```
OpAreaCount <- data.frame(table(OperatorAreaData$Operator))
names(OpAreaCount)[2] <- "AreaCount"
OperatorData$"AreaCount" <- cbind(OpAreaCount$AreaCount)
```

This is fairly straightforward, but I'm stuck in how to calculate the second column calculation with the condition of 50%.

Comment: Can you explain how your last column is calculated? Why `1, 1, 4`?

Comment: This column is calculated by counting the number of areas in which an operator owns more than 50% of locations **As an example:** Operator A operates in 1 Area in which it owns more than 50% of locations. So, In Tooting there are 500 Locations and Operator 'A' owns 400 (80%) Locations in Tooting. But it owns less than 50% in Torbay and Taunton, so the count is only 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

OperatorAreaData %>%
  inner_join(AreaData, by="Area") %>%
  group_by(Operator) %>%
  summarise(AreaCount = n_distinct(Area),
            Own_GE_50percent = sum(Locations > (SumLocations/2)))

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Operator AreaCount Own_GE_50percent
#   <fct>        <int>            <int>
# 1 A                3                1
# 2 B                3                1
# 3 C                5                4
```

You can use `AreaCount = n()` if you're sure you have unique `Area` values for each `Operator`.